# Does anybody know if there is any LINQ methodology for digital twin SQ

Tags: azure-digital-twins

Does anybody know if there is any LINQ methodology for digital twin SQL - just like LINQ to sql or LInQ to object etc?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, there isn't. It would make a good [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/9d500f96-f124-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0)